# Designing a 3-phase pure sine inverter. Where do I start?

Tags: inverter, three-phase

I'm trying to design a 3-phase pure sine inverter which will be powered by a 128 cell battery bank (3.0v-4.2v/384v-537v). Since 384v is still above the 325v peak of a 250Vrms sine wave, I figured I could build this without any transformers, just connecting an H-bridge to the battery and adjusting the SPWM to get the right output voltage (and implement a feedback system).

Now, the more I'm looking into this, the more I'm realizing that this isn't something I'll be able to do without some serious research.

I have some questions like:

- How do I filter the output of the H-bridge to get a sine wave without losing power? (I'm trying to keep the efficiency as high as possible)
- What's a good frequency for the SPWM? (I suppose the higher the better for smaller filter components as long as I keep an eye on the switching losses)
- How do I get 3 phases and a neutral (wye) out of this? At first I thought I'd just build 3 separate, 120° shifted, inverters and connect them all to 1 point (neutral). But now that I'm thinking about it, that's probably not a great idea since they won't be electrically insulated.

If someone could answer these for me, that'd be great, but I'm also looking for some stuff to read on this, to get a better grasp on how (3-phase) inverters work before trying to design one myself.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Indeed some serious research is needed. What is particularly useful is to study **existing designs** of "pure sine wave" inverters (at first, ignore the "3 phase" part). See and learn how they do it, try to understand **why** things are done in a certain way. Don't try to re-invent the wheel but start with the work of others and build on that knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I filter the output of the H-bridge to get a sine wave without losing power? (I'm trying to keep the efficiency as high as possible)

An ideal filter doesn't lose power, a filter built with lossy components does. So you have a classic cost/performance tradeoff, expensive low loss components or cheaper higher loss components.

> What's a good frequency for the SPWM? (I suppose the higher the better for smaller filter components as long as I keep an eye on the switching losses)

It should be at least above 20kHz, so you can't hear it. As you raise it further, the switching losses in the switches increases linearly with the switching frequency, but the components in the filter can shrink. You have another design tradeoff, losses in the switches versus size of the filter components. It's likely that filter component losses increase with frequency as well. Remember you're only trying to make 50/60 (maybe 400?) Hz out of this thing, so there's no need to go up to the frequencies that class D audio amplifiers do. One benefit of using very high frequencies is the potential for miniaturisation, do you need the smallest possible size? The answer to the size might allow you to choose between 30kHz and 300kHz.

> How do I get 3 phases and a neutral (wye) out of this? At first I thought I'd just build 3 separate, 120° shifted, inverters and connect them all to 1 point (neutral). But now that I'm thinking about it, that's probably not a great idea since they won't be electrically insulated

There are two alternatives. Run three half-bridge generators from the same supplies of +/- 400V, so you'd need two sets of batteries. Or, run three full bridge single phase bridge-tied load generators from three independent 400V batteries, connect them together at the neutral point.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I've been thinking about it. (Is there a way to quote parts of your post?) What sort of filter are you talking about? I know very little about filters but I suppose I need a low pass filter to filter out the spwm and get a 50hz sine out but if I google that, the first thing I come across is an RC filter, where all of the current has to flow through a resistor.

Comment: I'm not really looking for the smallest possible size, but I am looking for #1 high efficiency and #2 cheap components, so my guess would be that a smaller filter is usually also a cheaper filter. Which is why I would tend to go for a higher frequency and pick mosfets with low rise and fall times.

Comment: I'm not sure how those 7 points (3 inverters and the center tap) would need to be connected exactly. Thanks for your time

Comment: I figured you probably meant an LC filter, would a single LC filter be enough for output filtering of an inverter?

Comment: Yes, an LC filter. You would probably get away with only 2nd order, depending on what your specifications were. No, you're right, you'd need a +/- 350v battery, so two stacks of 128 batts, to get a centre tap the way I suggest, with all half bridges powered from the same supply. However, the way you suggest, you'd need 3 batteries to power three independent single phase full bridge BTL generators, connected together at the neutral point. Yes, edit my post, select what you want to quote, ctrl-C, close mine and go into yours, ctrl-V.

Comment: So I guess I'll need 256 cell battery packs then.. Not ideal but better than having to manage 3 separate 128 cell banks. (Do you have any idea what minimum safe pcb trace separation for 1kV dc is?) I guess the one thing that still puzzles me is that filter. Preferably, I'd have an output of about 10kW per phase, do the characteristics of the filter change as the load changes? If so, what can I do to have a nice 50hz sine at both no load and 10kW?

Comment: Also, would you be able to tell me (or point me to a formula) what kind of L and C values I'd be looking at at say a 300kHz spwm? Or maybe I should go even higher, to reduce required inductance since I'll probably need to parallel a few to handle the current and that lowers inductance. Thanks again

Comment: If you're asking these questions, don't start with 10kW, and don't start with 3 phase. Build something single phase and very small, and get your learning done cheaply before you commit big bucks

Comment: Yes, you're right, my plan is to try making a low voltage, 3 phase inverter from something like a +12v/-12v supply to experiment but I'm trying to gather information.